# Padrão de endpoints de API REST

Tags: laravel, api, rest

Estou criando uma aplicação semelhante ao Twitter usando Laravel e React, onde o banco possui as tabelas: Post, User, Relation, Mention e Repost. Na tela 'timeline' da aplicação serão exibidas informações de todas as tabelas do meu banco.

Minha dúvida é, eu construo um endpoint **/timeline** para o React pegar todas as informações de um endpoint, ou na tela timeline ele deve possuir um endpoint pra cada (/post, /user, etc...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No frontend, você vai fazer pedidos HTTP para obter as informações necessárias para a interface de usuário. Não importa como o método de obter as informações sejam implementadas no backend. O que for necessário deverá ser requerido por meio de um pedido HTTP.

Pode ser um só pedido, pode ser muitos. Depende de como o backend for construído. Depende de você se quiser criar uma rota exclusiva pro seu aplicativo React. Se sua visão for uma API que se tornará pública, talvez não seja uma boa idéia. Acho que sua pergunta se encaixa no tema de boa prática para construir uma API. Se fosse eu, eu deixaria a API do backend modularizada para cada recurso, independente de que frontend for utilizá-la.